# Center a link vertically along with the headline next to it

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML header. It's a simple title bar with a back href.
However the headline `<h1>` is placed UNDER the href. I don't want that.
What I want is a simple title bar with a centered headline and a button 
which is on the same height like the headline.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'sans-serif';
}

header {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #888888;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#">Back</a>
    <h1>Photo Framed</h1>
</header>
```

How can i achieve that?

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

Since I'm very new to the world of HTML and CSS, I have no clue how to not let the title get pushed down by the back href. Later I want to replace the href by an image. It should be the same with the image. I have a padding of 15px for the title. I also want 15px padding for the back href and want it to be on the same height like the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a `line-height` and make the value the same as the `h1`'s height.

```
a {
    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epxhnohr/

Or use absolute `position` instead of `float`, and combine with the `line-height`.

```
a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epxhnohr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/Lcy2kf0j/

```
header{
    height: 40px;
}
header *{
    line-height: 40px;
}
a{
    float: left;

}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could work with a `display:inline-block;` i guess.